# G++ doesn't allow me to define a member function named "major"

Tags: c++, g++, libc, gcc-warning, libstdc++

So, today I was coding some unit tests, and suddenly G++ gave me an unexpected warning regarding GNU C and one of my member functions named `major`. Why can't I have a member function named `major` without triggering G++?

This is a minimally viable test snippet:

```
// Any of these includes trigger the warnings
#include <random>
#include <cstdlib>

class my_class {
public:
    void major() const;
};

inline void my_class::major() const {}

int main(void) {
    my_class my_obj;
    my_obj.major();
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the output of the compilation (using `g++ --std=c++14 -o test-gcc-major test-gcc-major.cpp`):

```
[flisboac@sonic ~]$ uname -a && lsb_release -a && g++ -v && g++ --std=c++14 -o test-gcc-major test-gcc-major.cpp && ./test-gcc-major 
Linux sonic 4.12.10-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Aug 30 12:18:42 CEST 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux
LSB Version:    1.4
Distributor ID: Arch
Description:    Arch Linux
Release:    rolling
Codename:   n/a
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.1.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: /build/gcc-multilib/src/gcc/configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=https://bugs.archlinux.org/ --enable-languages=c,c++,ada,fortran,go,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-libmpx --with-system-zlib --with-isl --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-clocale=gnu --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libssp --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --enable-lto --enable-plugin --enable-install-libiberty --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-multilib --disable-werror --enable-checking=release --enable-default-pie --enable-default-ssp
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.1.1 20170630 (GCC) 
test-gcc-major.cpp:7:13: warning: In the GNU C Library, "major" is defined
 by <sys/sysmacros.h>. For historical compatibility, it is
 currently defined by <sys/types.h> as well, but we plan to
 remove this soon. To use "major", include <sys/sysmacros.h>
 directly. If you did not intend to use a system-defined macro
 "major", you should undefine it after including <sys/types.h>.
  void major() const;
             ^~~~~~~~                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
test-gcc-major.cpp:10:13: warning: In the GNU C Library, "major" is defined
 by <sys/sysmacros.h>. For historical compatibility, it is
 currently defined by <sys/types.h> as well, but we plan to
 remove this soon. To use "major", include <sys/sysmacros.h>
 directly. If you did not intend to use a system-defined macro
 "major", you should undefine it after including <sys/types.h>.
 inline void my_class::major() const {}
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
test-gcc-major.cpp:14:13: warning: In the GNU C Library, "major" is defined
 by <sys/sysmacros.h>. For historical compatibility, it is
 currently defined by <sys/types.h> as well, but we plan to
 remove this soon. To use "major", include <sys/sysmacros.h>
 directly. If you did not intend to use a system-defined macro
 "major", you should undefine it after including <sys/types.h>.
  my_obj.major();
```

The warning is triggered for every line referencing the member function in any way. Also, I can't undefine anything, because I'm implementing a library, and that burden should fall under the final user.

So, does someone know why this warning is being raised up? I'm not even using C anywhere in my code. All I'm using is `<random>`, which is not C, per se (but may include a "C" library, who knows?).

In any case, is there any way to detect the need and undefine `major` at compile-time (e.g. with some pre-processor voodoo)?

**UPDATE:** I'm using `<random>`, not `<cstdlib>`. I just found out that `<cstdlib>`also triggers the warning.

Comment: The error is self explanatory, I would say. It's a macro in `sys/sysmacros.h`. You are lucky GCC warns you instead of just compiling the code and letting you scratch your head at the strange things that will happen.

Comment: The error message explains the problem in perfectly good English. You also shouldn't be using `random` in new C++ code.

Comment: @n.m I'm using <random>. Please read the post more carefully.

Comment: @StoryTeller The question is whether there's any way to check for this at compile-time, and not un-define stuff that is not defined in another compiler. Is there a range of versions I should focus on?

Comment: Did you read the error message?

Comment: @n.m I'm not using `std::rand`. In fact, I haven't mentioned `std::rand` at all. My snippet DOES NOT contain any reference to this function (in fact, it has no logic whatsoever), and yet it triggers the warning. Also, for the people asking me to undefine `major`, what if a client depends on such definition? Can I just break user code indiscriminately then?

Comment: Sorry got my random number libraries confused. Please disregard.

Comment: Just a note: older gcc (4.8.4) with `-std=c++11` doesn't generate any warning at all. I can't check with `-std=c++14` right now. Don't know though whether older version doesn't have any issue with `major` or it is just  silently ignoring anything that may got broken.

Comment: @taskinoor look at the preprocessed source, does it still have `major`?

Comment: @taskinoor `pacman -Qs glibc` gives me `local/glibc 2.25-7 (base)` and `local/lib32-glibc 2.25-7`, and that version was released in 5 Feb 2017. Searching the glibc's Bugzilla, I found an [open bug report](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=19239) for a problem that's very much the same as mine. As per the [comment 10](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=19239#c10), it seems that "for software portable beyond GNU/Linux there is no workaround available atm."

Comment: @n.m. after preprocessing (`-E`) the function got renamed to `void gnu_dev_major () const;`. There isn't any other macro `major`. I don't know why `gnu_dev_` prefix got added. And my glibc version is `2.19`.

Comment: @n.m. just tried to look in `random` and `cstdlib` on my system. None of them seems to include `sys/sysmacros.h`. If it matters, I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @taskinoor run `g++ -H ...`, see the output.

Comment: @taskinoor According to [this page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macro-Arguments.html), "Whitespace is not a preprocessing token," so my guess is that the preprocessor is applying the macro regardless of space between the identifier (that is defined at pre-processing time, even though it's function-like) and the opening parenthesis of the _supposed_ macro function call. I wonder if that would happen if we could put something between the identifier and the parenthesis...

Comment: "the function got renamed" yep that's the problem. Your glibc is too old and doesn't include the deprecation warning, it just breaks the code silently.

Comment: If you make `major` a function with 2 arguments or a data member or a template, it is likely to break loudly. Even if it seems to be working, you don't want your stuff silently renamed by a rogue macro.

Comment: @n.m. yes, I can see `sys/sysmacros.h` with `-H`. Looks like I need to update.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is OK to undefine the macro, which is here for backward compatibility only, will soon be removed, and shouldn't have been there in the first place. There is no way this `#undef` can possibly break or harm user code.

If your users need the macro *and* your header included in the same source file, let them sort it out themselves. They would have to anyway, whether you include an offending header or not and whether you `#undef` it or not.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the solution is to stop trying to make a member called `major`.  Otherwise you'll need to `#undef major` which seems quite unpleasant for a library to do (presumably in a header file).

Comment: I was hoping there would be a feature flag or `#define` that would avoid this warning without breaking a client that would need this definition. Perhaps its better to be as non intrusive as possible, so renaming the function is the way to go. That's quite unfortunate, because `major` is the best name in my domain for the purposes of that function.